# asp.net mvc html.password set value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a html.password helper control on an edit profile type screen. Is there a way to set the value of this when the page first loads so that if the user doesn't want to change their password, the existing one gets passed back to the controller.

Thanks
Nick

Comment: I wonder why this got a markdown? The questions seems reasonably clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Html.Password` helper does not use `ViewData` automatically (see ASP.NET MVC source, InputExtensions.cs file, line 78, line 184). You need something like this:

```
<%= Html.Password("password", ViewData["password"]) %>
```

**UPDATED:**

Tested in Opera 10b, Firefox 3.5, Internet Explorer 8

Comment: The HTML spec is somewhat fuzzy on this, but some browsers will not render an initial value for a "password" field, so you have to resort to additional data-binding or Javascript tricks to set a value.

Comment: For example Opera10b and Firefox 3.5 renders

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I know this used to be the case, because I've had to deal with it...

Comment: The HTML 4.01 spec states "Note that the current value is the text entered by the user, not the text rendered by the user agent.", and "The control's 'current value' is first set to the initial value. Thereafter, the control's current value may be modified through user interaction and scripts.  A control's initial value does not change."

Answer (score 4):

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but coming at this from the user's point of view, would the user want their password being transmitted like this. I know I would not want any of my passwords transmitted anywhere unless it was absolutely necessary.

Most sites that I've seen only require a new password in the profile screen if it needs to be changed. If it is to remain the same and not updated the blank password fields are an indication of that. It also means that you can store the passwords in a more secure way (e.g. a one way salted hash) that does not permit password retrieval in any way (which if they could be retrieved would be a potential security risk in itself)

Comment: I agree with this, but I suppose there may be certain use cases where this may be useful.

Comment: In which use cases would it be helpful to have the website pre-populate the update password fields on a form with the existing password over leaving the password fields blank?

Comment: The question was not about "In which use-cases would it be helpful?" but about "how to do this?".

Comment: I do understand your comment Colin and I may re-consider the workflow of the process.

Comment: @eu-ge-ne My comment was in response to tvanfosson. I realise what the original question was, but if I think the original question points in the wrong direction (or down an ineffcient path) then I will always point that out. I cannot force the original poster to accept my advice, but I offer it freely in case it is useful or it is something that was not originally thought about.

Comment: @Colin - just speculating, let's say your application allowed the user to synchronize with a third-party web site.  You need to get their credentials for the external site.  As a convenience, on the page where you get those credentials you supply the user's existing id/password for your site in case the user wants to reuse them for the other site.

Comment: To tie all these together, the simplest way to solve the problem is to test whether the user entered anything in the password field, and then follow normal processes to change the password.  As Colin pointed out, best-practices would prevent the password from being retrieved anyway.

Comment: @Colin Mackay - Your answer is helpfull. But I totally agree with tvanfosson's comment - you can not cover all possible situations

Comment: I agree that there will always be some cases where you want to show the existing password. However, you don't do that be pre-populating the password field, but by writing it out as plain text. Pre-populating the password field is an *unnecessary* case of transmitting the user's password.